# What can a hostile magic user do with your blood?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells

A GM had a city guard ask a vial of blood from every visitor in order to verify identity in cases of small crime and the like.

If that city guard, or other members of government had access to that blood vial, what sort of dangers would my character be exposed to? I'm basically looking for spells/other actions which are enabled by having some blood and are harmful/show things about my character.

The only thing I found myself was [Blood Biography](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-biography/), but while annoying, from a broader fantasy background I assumed some more malicious stuff was possible. Is it?

Comment: ***Trivia:*** In *Pathfinder*'s antecedent *D&D 3.5* a vial of blood was a surefire way to know that you'd framed later by a sentient ice sculpture *via* the [*simulacrum*](http://dndsrd.net/spellsS.html#simulacrum) spell, but with *Pathfinder*'s change to the material components of the [*simulacrum*](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/simulacrum/) spell that's—perhaps even more worryingly—no longer a thing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Divinations

Assuming the guards are labeling the vials of blood an individual could be tracked by a diviner to conduct an investigation for legit or less than legitimate reasons. This can lead to malicious things like [Scry and Die tactics](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?112056-Scry-and-Die-Tactics) being used against you.

Were a crime to occur in the city, the guards could conduct an investigation to determine the relevant parties involved and verify those results with divination magic. At the time of collection, the *[Blood Biography](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/b/blood-biography/)* spell can be used to affirm that the labels are correct.

The *[Scry](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/s/scrying/)* spell in particular is much more likely to succeed when the caster has access to some blood (-10 penalty on the save) and by labeling the vials the caster can reduce the save bonus to secondhand familiarity (+5 bonus on the save). From there, spells like *[Locate Creature](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/l/locate-creature/)* or [Teleport](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/t/teleport/) could be used to bring the diviner into close proximity to the individual for capture (or killing).

All these spells are 5th level or less and depending on the size of the city are probably readily accessible for authorities to use if they see fit.